# How to enable PostgreSQL driver for PDO for php 7?

Tags: drivers, php, postgresql

I have a ubuntu 14.4 server with apache2 and php 7.1.6.

I also have PostgreSQL 9.3 installed on it. I now need to connect to this data from php code, using PDO.

I have tried the following:

1. Install Pgsql driver with:
   `sudo apt install php7.0-pgsql`
2. Now when I try to enable postgres PDO drivers using `sudo phpenmod pdo_pgsql`, I get the following error messages:

`WARNING: Module pdo_pgsql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available`

How do you correctly install & enable the PDO drivers for PostGres for php 7?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You've been running php7.1 while you installed php7.0 pgsql module.

Try `php -v` to check your version and install `php7.1-pgsql`.

Answer (score 3):

Also you need to uncomment these lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

in `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini` .

Comment: Also, sudo phpenmod pdo_pgsql

Answer (score 2):

The following worked on Ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.1

```
sudo apt install php7.1-pgsql
sudo phpenmod pdo_pgsql
sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others said, try:

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_pgsql
```

Comment: Please be specific. Which other commands should one use before the one you wrote? Otherwise the answer is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following:

1. Try `php -v` to check your version
2. Install `php7.1-pgsql`
3. Enable postgres PDO drivers using `sudo phpenmod pdo_pgsql`
4. Restart `postgres` service.